# Google Custom Search API results empty while normal search has results

Tags: search, search-engine, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

When I use the google custom search api, and search for a string sich as an email, the result back is nothing. However when I use the normal google search engine on the website, i get 2 results back. How come this happens? Is it an error in my custom search call or is it just because the API does return different results due to numerous reasons I have heard about such as to reduce harvesting.

Custom Search Call (note iv removed the key and cx values):
https://www.googleapis.com:443/customsearch/v1/?fields=items%28link%2Ctitle%29&key=[key]&cx=[cx]&safe=high&q=%22jimmy.smith%40gmail.com%22&num=10

Normal search:
https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22jimmy.smith%40gmail.com%22

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue with GCS, it doesn't return simple queries that "normal" Google does. Even the RapidAPI.com API of Google Search finds what I'm looking for, but Google itself doesn't. Very strange.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar no I didn't, I ended up using a third party SERP service.

Comment: Does it still use Custom Search Engine you built?

Comment: Also, what was the SERP you tried? We are evaluating a different approach ourselves, which is using ElasticSearch (though we aren't 100% sure on the implementation side) @dearsina Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I used serpsbot.com. Which was alright. They're always playing a cat-and-mouse game with Google blocking their IPs, so there may be better providers out there.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you configuration for "Custom Search" in your search engine app located at Setup -> Basic (Tab) -> Sites to Search (Section) is set to "Search the entire web but emphasize include site" .